# Proving basic theorems of topology.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Hey guys, need some help here. I was told by your instructor that there are three methods of proof: (1) direct, (2) by contraposition,
and (3) indirect (by contradiction). 
There is also a technique of proof by mathematical induction. A counter-example is essentially a proof that a statement is false, but it requires existence; that is, a counter-example must be specific and name individuals and sets.

However, I am unsure about how to proceed. First few statements looks like it can be proved directly using U as a statement such as "a set of prime numbers from 0-10" and then we can say that P(x) as {2,3,5,7} but I dont know how to deal with Q(x).

What about statements (7) and (8)? those two are conditions or statements of continuity and uniform continuity which I studied in advanced calculus. Should those proofs be straight forward? I am little confused with those since the course is topology and its a question of topology.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is not *general topology*. It might be *logic*, or, *proof-writting*.

Comment: Only (7) and (8) have any topology expressions in them, nonetheless there is no topological content in what you are asked to do, just logic and proof techniques.

Comment: hmm, I can prove statements 7 and 8 but I dont know how 2 do the rest, can you please help me in figuring out some of them. I am pretty sure that I will get most of them if I get an idea about how to solve them. I need idea for 1st few of those statements. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Azif00: maybe, but the subject is topology. So, I thought I need to work in that way or direction. Anyway can you pls help me in figuring out the logic for the statements because I am not able to figure out those.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun.  You cannot prove 7 and 8 for discontinuous functions.

Comment: Yeah, because statement 7 is the condition for continuity and 8 is for uniform continuity. Hence, they definitely have to work for continuous functions. If a function is discontinuous, then it won’t work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed statements have no topological content, even no interpretations for the names like $U$, $P$, and $f$. So their form provides a little help for their proofs.

> If you skip this you will be sorry!

I’m working in topology for more than twenty years and I can assure you that if you follow this you’ll be sorry. This is because, as Nicholas Bourbaki wrote, “the mathematician does not work like a machine, nor as the workingman on a moving belt; we can not over-emphasize the fundamental role played in his research by a special intuition, which is not the popular sense-intuition, but rather a kind of direct divination (ahead of all reasoning) of the normal behavior, which he seems to have the right to expect of mathematical beings, with whom a long acquintance has made him as familiar as with the beings of the real world”. So in order to prove a theorem usually you have not to look for a specific sequence of logic formulas, but to understand its matter (math is fun, we do it  because it is interesting and beautiful). Then often you’ll be able see a way to prove it. This is easy when you are solving exercises. But when your mathematical intuition is developed enough, sometimes you can solve open problems. A famous mathematician (and topologist) Henri Poincaré provides more advanced reflections of a work of this intuition in the beginning of “[Mathematical Creation](https://paradise.caltech.edu/ist4/lectures/Poincare_Reflections.pdf)”.