# Is it possible to find non constant, continuous simple function?

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is it possible to find non constant, continuous simple function ? While calculating Lebesgue integral of $f(x) =x^{2}$ on $ \mathbb R $.
We have constructed simple function which is basically function with finite range .
I was wondering will there exist any simple function which is continuous and non constant on any arbitrary space

Comment: Simple functions take a finite number of values and cannot be continuous.

Comment: What about in general space (topological space... ). It has to continuous then each connected component of domain but it is not possible in R.

Comment: Continous simple functions must be constant at each connected component of the domain. If the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ (which is connected), the continuous simple function has to be constant.

Comment: Ok, but does exist any other space where it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition.** A space $X$ admits a non-constant continuous simple function iff $X$ is not connected.

*Proof*. $(\Rightarrow)$ Let $f:X\to\Bbb R$ be a non-constant continuous simple function. Pick any $y\in f(X)$. It is easy to check that $f^{-1}(y)$ and $X\setminus f^{-1}(y)$ is a partition of the space $X$ into its disjoint non-empty open subsets.

$(\Leftarrow)$ If $X$ is a union of two its disjoint non-empty open subsets $A$ and $B$ then the characteristic function of the set $A$ is a non-constant continuous simple function on $X$. $\square$

Comment: can u tell me which reference book are you using?

Comment: @SHREYAPANDEY I don't understand the question. My answer is based on basic definitions, and I don't need special references for it.

Comment: Actually, I want to know can we just manipulate the definition and come with proposition like this?

Comment: @SHREYAPANDEY I guess we can, but this is a way for a blind proof-writing automaton. We, humans, think differently, see , for instance my answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519327/proving-basic-theorems-of-topology/3548198#3548198) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003842/is-it-usual-to-have-no-intuition-to-certain-proofs-and-simply-do-them-mechanical/2010097#2010097).